# Backup selfmade IOS apps

Tags: ios, backup

I have created a few apps in Swift with a lot of data. This apps are not in the Appstore.

Is there a possibility to save the Apps and the data in the iTunes Backup?

If I do a restore my own apps are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the ipa with you, and install it using iTunes whenever you want. Another way would be installing it using XCode.